# Existence of the solution for SDE with Gaussian Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, differential-equations

I'm interested in the existence of the solution for a non-Ito SDE. Sloppy notation but assume a SDE given by

$\dot{x}=f(x),\quad f(x)∼GP(0,k(x,x′)),$

where $f$ is a Gaussian Process with kernel $k$. It's quite easy to show that for some kernels (Lipschitz, etc.) all realizations of $f$ lead to ODEs with unique solutions. However, is there a way to transfer this information to the SDE? E.g. as all realizations lead to well-behaved ODEs -> there exists a solution for the SDE? Or is there any other way how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Hi: There are definitely knowledgeable math people  here for sure so no disrespect intended  but you might be better off asking that question on quant.stackexchange because that type of material is dealt with over there quite frequently.